# Use Jasmine to test a jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using the library **angular-minicolors** (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) in an angular controller:

```
angular.element("myelement").minicolors({
    position: 'top left',
    change: function() {
        //code to execute on color change
    }
})
```

However, when testing this controller, Karma throws the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.element("myelement").minicolors({
>           position: 'top left',
>           change: function() {
>               //code to execute on color change
>           }
>       })'

My guess is that it doesn't recognize the library **angular-minicolors**.
However, on the navigator, everything works well.

I would really welcome any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like my test didn't know about **minicolors** since I forgot to add another dependency **jquery.minicolors.js** in my karma configuration:

```
files: [
    'src/main/resources/static/js/lib/angular-minicolors.js',
    'src/main/resources/static/js/lib/jquery.minicolors.js',
    ...
]
```